# Can't send Browser_Back/Forward via SendInput() (only on Surface Pro 2)

Tags: c#, sendinput

some days ago, I got my Microsoft Arc Touch Mouse Surface Edition. Unfortunately, it doesn't have Forward/Back-Buttons (it performs only Page-Up/Page-Down).

So, I've written a little program, that catches the press of the Page_Up/Page_Down Keys and sends instead the Browser-Back/-Forward Button.

On my PC (Win 8.1 Pro) this works quite well. However, on my Surface Pro 2 (for which the program primarly was written) it won't send the Browser_Back-/Forward-Buttons.
For every other key the program seems to work (like Space, letters, numbers).

Here the code for sending Keycodes:

```
      public static uint send(short keyCode) {

        INPUT structure = new INPUT();
        structure.type = (int)InputType.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
       structure.ki.wVk = keyCode;

        structure.ki.dwFlags = (int)KEYEVENTF.KEYDOWN;
        structure.ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();

        INPUT input2 = new INPUT();
        structure.type = (int)InputType.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        structure.ki.wVk = keyCode;

        input2.mi.dwFlags = (int)KEYEVENTF.KEYUP;
        input2.ki.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();

        INPUT[] pInputs = new INPUT[] { structure, input2 };

        return SendInput(2, pInputs, Marshal.SizeOf(structure));
    }
```

And here the KeyboardHook:

```
       public static int KeyHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {

        KeyHookStruct myKeyHookStruct =
            (KeyHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KeyHookStruct));

        if (nCode < 0) {
            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        } else {

            if (wParam == (IntPtr)0x0100) {


                int keyCode = myKeyHookStruct.vkCode;
                if (keyCode == 33) {

                    Input.send(0xA7);
                } else if (keyCode == 34) {

                    Input.send(0xA6);
                } else {
                    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
                }


            }

            return 1;

        }

    }
```

So, if the Page-Down/page-Up button on my keyboard is pressed, the send()-Method is called.
0xA6 and 0xA7 are the Keycodes for Browser_Back and Browser_Forward.

On my Surface, the Page-Up/Page-Down buttons are recognized correctly. The send()-Method is also called, but it won'T send the correct Keycodes. According to Spy++,  send() isn't sending anything if the Keycode is 0xA6 or 0xA7 (on my PC it works).

Where is the problem with the Surface Pro 2? What could I do, that it works, or how could I determine why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is wrong, as you never set `type` for `input2` (the code use `structure.type`)

EDIT:

From MSDN docs for [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx):

> This function fails when it is blocked by UIPI. Note that neither
>   GetLastError nor the return value will indicate the failure was caused
>   by UIPI blocking.
>
> This function is subject to UIPI. Applications are permitted to inject
>   input only into applications that are at an equal or lesser integrity
>   level.

You also should remove the call to `GetMessageExtraInfo`

New Edit:

I don't like the logic of your `KeyHookProc` function: if the message is NOT `WM_KEYDOWN` (0x0100), then you return 1...

I would go for:

```
if (wParam != (IntPtr)0x0100) {
   return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
} else {
   int keyCode = myKeyHookStruct.vkCode;
   if (keyCode == 33) {
      Input.send(0xA7);
   } else if (keyCode == 34) {
      Input.send(0xA6);
   } else {
      return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: oh, indeed. Changed the code, but it still don't work on my surface pro 2. Its like there are no page-up/down-keys. Absolutley nothing is send.

Comment: See updated answer. What can you tell us about the process which emit the keys? Is your hook in a DLL loaded by IE? And if yes, is that DLL loaded in a low level process? Use Process Explorer from sysinternals.

Comment: Integrity Level of my program is middle. Firefox/notepad is also on middle. I tried to run my .exe as administrator, so that it is on high level, but it still dont work. Now, i'll try it in secure mode. maybe there is a driver that interfere with my program.

EDIT: Seems to be a driver problem. In secure mode it works like it should.

Comment: Maybe you should also monitor/check the return codes from SendInput

Comment: @Rul3r Did you try with my version (not returning 1 in some case)?